# Geometry Nodes - Curve To Point - Rotation Problem for door

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry

I want to add a door model between the two vertexes I selected in the geometry node. but I wonder how can I fix the reverberation of the doors in the corner? Thank you :)
[image]

[video file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwKV7kkMUok)

[image]

---

If I move to point, this setup not work.

Result.
[image]

Setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

it's not a good idea to capture the tangent from points, which you are "moving" afterwards by resample curve.

Comment: try this node setup:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


result:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUf7w.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysSUJ.png

it's not a good idea to capture the tangent from points, which you are "moving" afterwards by resample curve.

Comment: i don't understand why you are copying my answer into a comment....

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, thak all for answer.
Fix: I add split Edge node, and fix.
[image]